# COUNT and DISTINCT queries in CYPHER causing javaheap memory error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The cypher query:

```
MATCH (n1:ANIMAL)-[r:COHABITS]-(n2:ANIMAL)
RETURN distinct[id(n1),id(n2)] as tups, count(distinct[id(n1),id(n2)]) AS count
LIMIT 5
```

Never finishes, i.e. the query keeps running until neo4j encounters a javaheap memory failure. However when I execute:

```
MATCH (n1:ANIMAL)-[r:COHABITS]-(n2:ANIMAL)
RETURN n1,r,n2
LIMIT 5
```

I get a fast response.

Is there a reason/workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `distinct` Cypher needs to build up the result set in memory to check if a new result is already present in the set. Without distinct, it just streams the results and only has very little need for heap space.

Depending on the number of `:COHABITS` relationships you need to increase your heap space settings in `neo4j-wrapper.conf`